# Is there a way to override c3_chart_internal_fn.generateResize on c3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, resize, overriding, c3

I have been using d3js all these days and recently found out that c3js makes the job easier.

Now, I have the graph and when I try to resize the page the graph redraws itself. Is there a way I can override this? Tried Onresize and Onresized, they are not overriding the default behavior.
Found from the code that when I resize, it calls this function 
https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/c3.js#L968

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just overwrite it for your chart instance. Something like

```
chart.internal.generateResize = function () { }
```

That said, what you probably want is **if there are no other resize handlers**

```
window.onresize = null;
```

Comment: Awesome, I had to use c3.chart.internal.fn.generateResize = function () {} Thanks